# Resolving circular dependency hell for libX11 and libXi

Tags: x11, dependencies

I'm trying to install `X11` from source.

Source files from [some repository](http://www.t2-project.org/packages/):

```
libX11-1.6.0.tar.gz
libXi-1.7.1.901.tar.gz
```

`libX11-1.6.0`

```
paulk@node005:libX11-1.6.0$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/software
XKBExtDev.c:35:31: fatal error: X11/extensions/XI.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [XKBExtDev.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/paulk/libX11-1.6.0/src/xkb'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/paulk/libX11-1.6.0/src'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/paulk/libX11-1.6.0/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

but for `libXi-1.7.1.901`

```
paulk@node005:libXi-1.7.1.901$ 
configure: error: Package requirements (xproto >= 7.0.13 x11 >= 1.4.99.1 xextproto >= 7.0.3 xext >= 1.0.99.1 inputproto >= 2.2.99.1) were not met:

No package 'x11' found
No package 'xext' found
No package 'inputproto' found
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: What do you mean by `libX11-1.6.0` and `libXi-1.7.1.901` as source files? Where are you getting these sources? Are you installing X.org or some other X11 distribution? What build process are you following? Are you building the whole thing, or do you just want to build one module?

Comment: @Gilles: Those are the package names (I've left out the .tar.gz - thought it would be obvious). I got them from www.t2-project.org/packages/libxi.html‎. I don't know what a 'build process' is. Please specify. I want to install X11. I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: There are many distributions of X11. T2 uses X.org (it's the most common one). So what you're really doing is building T2 packages. This is critical information! Are you running T2? Is this the first time you compile a T2 package? X11 isn't the easiest thing to compile, are you sure you really want to build everything yourself?

Comment: @Gilles: you ask a lot of (good) questions! ;-) Well, then I think I'll find another way round. Thanks, though.

Comment: The obvious question is what are you trying to do? If you want to run a Unix-like operating system that uses X11 - and as far as I know only Unix-like systems do - then these operating systems are typically packaged in precompiled binary form so you don't need to compile anything. (Even the exceptions like Gentoo have builtin recipes that essentially involve pressing a button.) These include the various Linux-based OS's (popularly called distributions) as well as the *BSDs. Bottom line - you shouldn't be trying to compile and install X11 unless you have a really, really good reason to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you're building from the upstream X.Org sources, `X11/extensions/XI.h` comes from the `inputproto` package, not libXi itself.

You can see it in the git browser under http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/inputproto/tree/.